# Creating a constraint for a phone or zip code in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, constraints

Creating the following table (MySQL 8.0):

```
create table Customer_Dim(
customer_ID     int not null,
FirstName       varchar(30) not null,
LastName        varchar(30) not null,
Gender          char(1) not null CHECK (gender in ('m','f')),
Street1         varchar(100) not null,
Street2         varchar(100) null,
City            varchar(30) not null,
StateAbbrev     char(2) not null,
ZipCode         char(5) not null CHECK (ZipCode LIKE repeat('[0-9]',5)),
PrimaryPhone    varchar(10) not null CHECK (PrimaryPhone LIKE repeat('[0-9]',10)),
EmailAddress    varchar(50) default null,
constraint custkey Primary Key(customer_ID)
);
```

but when I enter the following insert statement:

```
insert into Customer_DIM
values (10001, 'Josh', 'Dexter', 'M', '123 E Elm st.', null, 'Denver', 'CO', '80002', '2023459767', 'test@aol.com')
```

It fails the check on phone and zipCode. From what I could read it should work?

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using? Below version 8 check constraints are accepted in `CREATE TABLE` statements without any error or warning but they're never enforced later on.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-check-constraints.html

Comment: I simulate you code in my engine MySQL v5.7.31 and works fine!.
Maybe is your version.

Comment: Like @stickybit say. He has explained the situation.

Comment: I'm on 8.0.21 64 bit community actually

Comment: FWIW, I think these sorts of checked should be being primarily done in application code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that a `regexp` is needed over `repeat` (which repeats chars)

Using `repeat` would expect something like this:

```
mysql> select repeat('[0-9]', 5);

+---------------------------+
| repeat('[0-9]', 5)        |
+---------------------------+
| [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] |
+---------------------------+
```

So, use a `regexp` instead:

```
create table Customer_Dim(
customer_ID     int not null,
FirstName       varchar(30) not null,
LastName        varchar(30) not null,
Gender          char(1) not null CHECK (gender in ('m','f')),
Street1         varchar(100) not null,
Street2         varchar(100) null,
City            varchar(30) not null,
StateAbbrev     char(2) not null,
ZipCode         char(5) not null CHECK (ZipCode regexp '[0-9]{5}'),
PrimaryPhone    varchar(10) not null CHECK (PrimaryPhone regexp'[0-9]{10}'),
EmailAddress    varchar(50) default null,
constraint custkey Primary Key(customer_ID)
);
```

Same (good) example insert:

```
insert into Customer_Dim
values (10001, 'Josh', 'Dexter', 'M', '123 E Elm st.', null, 'Denver', 'CO', '80002', '2023459767', 'test@aol.com')
```

Bad phone example insert:

```
insert into Customer_Dim
values (10001, 'Josh', 'Dexter', 'M', '123 E Elm st.', null, 'Denver', 'CO', '80002', '202359767', 'test@aol.com')
```

Gives the error:

> Check constraint 'Customer_Dim_chk_3' is violated.

Bad zip example insert:

```
insert into Customer_Dim
values (10001, 'Josh', 'Dexter', 'M', '123 E Elm st.', null, 'Denver', 'CO', '8002', '2023459767', 'test@aol.com')
```

Gives the error:

> Check constraint 'Customer_Dim_chk_2' is violated.

DB [fiddle example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c3b147463a59487974ecab6afb645230) with all of the above info.
(including the `repeat` example last)

Know that the MySQL check constraints were parsed but ignored before version 8.0.16:

[image]

Comment: Mind that `CHECK` constraints are enforced starting on MySQL 8.0.16. Before that version the constraint is stored but not checked.

Comment: Yes, that is true.